# How do I serialize and deserialize a dictionary's values correctly?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to figure out how to do it right. So far I'm using this method to serialize a list of objects:

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyInfo));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("SerializedValues.xml"))
{
    foreach (var o in dic.Values)
        serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
}
```

And it turns into a list of separate XML files, each with its own header, but all in one file. I'm assuming that is not right.

Then I try deserializing it and it gives me the following error:

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 5, position 17.

And that's exactly where the next XML header begins. So I guess I'm serializing it wrong.

There's also the issue that comes from the fact deserialization returns a single object, which already sounds wrong because I'm expecting a list of sorts.

How do I serialize it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

How about serialize the whole dictionary?

EDIT:  OK, how about as a List of KeyValuePair?

```
var list = dic.ToList();
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("SerializedValues.xml"))
    s.Serialize(file, list);
```

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String, blah-blah],[MyProject.MyInfo, blah-blah] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by converting the values to an array prior to serialization:

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyInfo[]));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("SerializedValues.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, dic.Values.ToArray());
}
```

And deserialize it like this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("SerializedValues.xml"))
{
    var array = (MyInfo[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    foreach (var v in array)                
        dic[v.id] = v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your solution works for this one specific case - because the Value also has information about the Key - I would still go for a more general solution.

The modified answer of agentnega will work as well, even if the Value has no information about the key.

My favorite though is the SerializableDictionary. Because there is no additional work in (de)serialization! Taken from here:
http://csharpcodewhisperer.blogspot.co.at/2013/06/namespace-xmlserializabledictionary.html

```
namespace XMLSerializableDictionary
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
  using System.Xml;
  using System.Xml.Schema;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  [Serializable]
  [XmlRoot("Dictionary")]
  public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
  {
    private const string DefaultTagItem = "Item";
    private const string DefaultTagKey = "Key";
    private const string DefaultTagValue = "Value";
    private static readonly XmlSerializer KeySerializer =
                                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));

    private static readonly XmlSerializer ValueSerializer =
                                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

    public SerializableDictionary() : base()
    {
    }

    protected SerializableDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
    {
    }

    protected virtual string ItemTagName
    {
        get { return DefaultTagItem; }
    }

    protected virtual string KeyTagName
    {
        get { return DefaultTagKey; }
    }

    protected virtual string ValueTagName
    {
        get { return DefaultTagValue; }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;

        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
        {
         return;
        }

        try
        {
            while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.ReadStartElement(this.ItemTagName);
                try
                {
                    TKey tKey;
                    TValue tValue;

                    reader.ReadStartElement(this.KeyTagName);
                    try
                    {
                        tKey = (TKey)KeySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.ReadEndElement();
                    }

                    reader.ReadStartElement(this.ValueTagName);
                    try
                    {
                        tValue = (TValue)ValueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.ReadEndElement();
                    }

                    this.Add(tKey, tValue);
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.ReadEndElement();
                }

                reader.MoveToContent();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair in this)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(this.ItemTagName);
            try
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(this.KeyTagName);
                try
                {
                    KeySerializer.Serialize(writer, keyValuePair.Key);
                }
                finally
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

                writer.WriteStartElement(this.ValueTagName);
                try
                {
                    ValueSerializer.Serialize(writer, keyValuePair.Value);
                }
                finally
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case though, the key can be a property returning hash sum from all object's field values.